# CS50 Filter Blur

Tags: cs50

I don't know what I do wrong. Its work on images but when output calculate answer is wrong.

ERROR output calculate

```
:( blur correctly filters middle pixel
    expected "127 140 149\n", not "145 160 169\n"
:( blur correctly filters pixel on edge
    expected "80 95 105\n", not "90 106 116\n"
:) blur correctly filters pixel in corner
:( blur correctly filters 3x3 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "70 85 95\n90 1..."
:( blur correctly filters 4x4 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "70 85 95\n90 1..."
```

this is my code.

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            double red = 0,green = 0,blue = 0;
            int count = 0;

            for (int m = 0; m < 3; m++)
            {
                int h = i+m-1;
                for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++)
                {
                    int w = j+n-1;
                    if(h > -1 && w > -1 && h < height && w < width)
                    {
                    red += image[h][w].rgbtRed;
                    green += image[h][w].rgbtGreen;
                    blue += image[h][w].rgbtBlue;
                    count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            red = 1.00*red/count;
            green = 1.00*green/count;
            blue = 1.00*blue/count;
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

May someone explain to me? I dont know why.

Comment: now i can solve my problems. Its because i not tmp the picture and rewrite before all calculating.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer ***not** as a comment*.